# Value read from database is NaN

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having an issue in Firebase where when I try to read a value from the database, I get an NaN value.

```
var database = firebase.database();

// Initializing our click count at 0
var clickCounter = 0;

// should read the value in the database:
database.ref().once('value').then(function(snapshot){
  clickCounter = snapshot.clickCount;
});

// On Click
$("#click-button").on("click", function() {

  // Add 1 to clickCounter
  clickCounter++;

  database.ref().set({
    clickCount: clickCounter
  });
```

Basically, if I remove the function to read the value from the database (line 3 of code), then the value in the database updates when I click the button. Upon refreshing, however, clicking the button resets the clickCount in the database to 1, since clickCounter is initialized at 0 in the first line.

Of course, this just means that I need to read the value from the database so that the browser refresh doesn't reset clickCounter to 0.

When I include the function to read the value from the database, I get this error:
[Uncaught Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains NaN in property 'clickCount'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74D0M.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From going over the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), I have seen this example:

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) ||   'Anonymous';
 // ...
});
```

In your code:

```
// should read the value in the database:
database.ref().once('value').then(function(snapshot){
  clickCounter = snapshot.clickCount; //<--- Missing access of .val()
});
```

You need to :

> clickCounter = snapshot.val().clickCount;